# After Change Route Jquery not Working , When Refresh again then work correctly

Tags: angular

When Load a Index.html file in angular , It's Work Perfect . But Whenever change the route Home Page to Another page then Jquery not load , Then I  check to console but in console is clear not any error to display,then Again i Refresh To that page and now it's working.in Short Whene change the route it;s not working jquery to another page.

I am creating a Two component with bootstrap designing . Whene change one component to second component jquery not load and again refreshing that page it's worked perfect

**index.html**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <base href="/">



  <!-- Basic Page Needs
 ================================================== -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JRTechnolab</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <!-- Mobile Specific Metas
================================================== -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"
    name="viewport">

  <!-- CSS
================================================== -->

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Template styles-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
  <!-- Responsive styles-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/responsive.css">
  <!-- FontAwesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!-- Animation -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/animate.css">
  <!-- Prettyphoto -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/prettyPhoto.css">
  <!-- Owl Carousel -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/owl.carousel.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/owl.theme.css">
  <!-- Flexslider -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/flexslider.css">
  <!-- Flexslider -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/cd-hero.css">
  <!-- Style Swicther -->
  <link id="style-switch" href="assets/css/presets/preset3.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements. All other JS at the end of file. -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>
  <!-- Style switcher start -->
  <div class="style-switch-wrapper">
    <div class="style-switch-button">
      <i class="fa fa-sliders"></i>
    </div>
    <h3>Style Options</h3>
    <button id="preset1" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"></button>
    <button id="preset2" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"></button>
    <button id="preset3" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"></button>
    <button id="preset4" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"></button>
    <button id="preset5" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"></button>
    <button id="preset6" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"></button>
    <br /><br />
    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary close-styler pull-right">Close X</a>
  </div>
  <!-- Style switcher end -->

  <div class="body-inner">

    <app-root></app-root>


    <!-- initialize jQuery Library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap jQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Style Switcher -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/style-switcher.js"></script>
    <!-- Owl Carousel -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/owl.carousel.js"></script>
    <!-- PrettyPhoto -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
    <!-- Bxslider -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
    <!-- CD Hero slider -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/cd-hero.js"></script>
    <!-- Isotope -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/isotope.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/ini.isotope.js"></script>
    <!-- Wow Animation -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/wow.min.js"></script>
    <!-- SmoothScroll -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/smooth-scroll/16.1.0/smooth-scroll.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Eeasing -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <!-- Counter -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.counterup.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Waypoints -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/waypoints.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Template custom -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { ContactComponent } from './contact/contact.component';

const routes: Routes = [
   { path: '', redirectTo:'home',pathMatch:'full' },
   { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
   { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent },
];

@NgModule({

imports: [
   CommonModule,RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
 ],
 exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Jquery Is not load to another page in angular latest 8 Plus Version

Comment: jquery does not work well with Angular anyways

Comment: Please include your jQuery code

Comment: Jquery load to index page in Script Tag

Comment: how did you included jquery?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>

Comment: may I know why exactly you need to use JQuery? Angular itself should be sufficient.

Comment: I try also do that but it's give me a same result.and i used bootstrap template so need to the jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dear Friends i solve this issue See Answer

In your component.ts file  have one function to name is ngOnInit.
So you can load Css and Js file path is ngOnInIt function.
This function basically run first to  when component is load first time.

Answer:

**home.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

@Component({
selector: 'app-home',
templateUrl: './home.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef,@Inject(DOCUMENT) private doc ) 
  { 
  }

  ngOnInit() 
  {

     let link1: HTMLLinkElement = this.doc.createElement('link');
     link1.setAttribute('rel', 'amphtml');
     link1.setAttribute('href', '../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css');
     this.doc.head.appendChild(link1);

     let link: HTMLLinkElement = this.doc.createElement('link');
     link.setAttribute('rel', 'amphtml');
     link.setAttribute('href', '../assets/css/owl.carousel.css');
     this.doc.head.appendChild(link);


     var s14 = document.createElement("script");
     s14.type = "text/javascript";
     s14.src = "../assets/js/bootstrap.min.js";
     this.elementRef.nativeElement.appendChild(s14);

     var s1 = document.createElement("script");
     s1.type = "text/javascript";
     s1.src = "../assets/js/style-switcher.js";
     this.elementRef.nativeElement.appendChild(s1);
   }
}
```

It's Working Fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is a logic problem of understanding Single page application, when using angular and the only part of the code that get loaded is the one in the

> app-root

i.e. the code in your component. 
If you want to use jquery with SPA then you need to add it to every parent component and always check that it is loaded. which is pointless in angular application. The best to do is to convert all jquery functions into angular functions(Typescript).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include external scripts or styles then you should add them to angular.json:

Use the npm jquery version and configure your angular.json:

```
 "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
          ...
          "scripts": [ "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" ]
          ...
}
```

With this way jquery becomes part of your bundle and is always available.